# PHP Generated HTML on Page is Not Functioning

Tags: php, mobile, xpath, dynamically-generated

I am dynamically generating the contents of a mobile page using XPATH(yes I've done my homework and this is the most viable option) which gets the HTML from the desktop website and displays it in mobile format.

The HTML on the mobile page is generated fine with the correct data, but the links aren't clickable and now a SELECT element which was not dynamically generated is no longer clickable either.

The menu button, however, is clickable. I am unsure if it's because the page is being generated after the DOM has loaded(if that's possible?), or what else could be the case, but the console isn't showing any errors.

[Link to the dev site](http://rosasfreelancedesign.com/dev/douglas/mobile/council-meetings.php?meeting=council-meetings)

Has anyone else experienced this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding

```
z-index: -1;
```

to the class `div.menu`.

If you inspect the page with web dev tools, you can notice that the `div.menu` covers the whole page, therefore the links in the content are not clickable.

Comment: @Eric Glad that I was able to help you, but as additional note: I just checked (as you already fixed it) and you have to remove the z-index: -1 when the menu is clicked, otherwise the navigation isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the dev site and am pretty sure this is because the top `div.menu` is "covering up" the rest of the page.  When you right click and inspect element, you'll see that menu is what you've selected.

If you turn off `position: fixed`, the layout gets wonky but the links are exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the DIV for the page and image is also not included so set **z-index: -1**